# Can't train my Tensorflow detector model in Google Cloud

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I'm trying to train my own Detector model based on Tensorflow sample and [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9). And I did succeed on training locally on a Macbook Pro. The problem is that I don't have a GPU and doing it on the CPU is too slow (about 25s per iteration).

This way, I'm trying to run on Google Cloud ML Engine following the [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_cloud.md), but I can't make it run properly.

My folder structures is described below:

```
+ data
 - train.record
 - test.record
+ models
 + train
 + eval
+ training
 - ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco
```

My steps to change from local training to Google Cloud training were:

1. Create a bucket in Google Cloud storage and copy my local folder structure with files;
2. Edit my `pipeline.config` file and change all paths from `Users/dev/detector/` to `gcc://bucketname/`;
3. Create a YAML file with the default configuration provided in the tutorial;
4. Run

   gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training object_detection_`date +%s` \ 
   --job-dir=gs://bucketname/models/train \
   --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz \
   --module-name object_detection.train \
   --region us-east1 \
   --config /Users/dev/detector/training/cloud.yml \
   -- \
   --train_dir=gs://bucketname/models/train \
   --pipeline_config_path=gs://bucketname/data/pipeline.config

Doing so, gives me the following error message from the MLUnits:

**The replica ps 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 49, in  from object_detection import trainer File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 27, in  from object_detection.builders import preprocessor_builder File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/preprocessor_builder.py", line 21, in  from object_detection.protos import preprocessor_pb2 File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/protos/preprocessor_pb2.py", line 71, in  options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR), TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got this [suggestion](https://medium.com/google-cloud/object-detection-tensorflow-and-google-cloud-platform-72e0a3f3bdd6) on Github. Still didn't have time to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution posted [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2739) by andersskog. It worked for me. I made a patch [here](https://gist.github.com/eranheres/5aa93df3eaae32c33b05d2d85befb90d). For manual fix follow the below instructions:

Make sure your yaml version is 1.4, eg:

```
trainingInput:
  runtimeVersion: "1.4"
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard_gpu
  workerCount: 5
  workerType: standard_gpu
  parameterServerCount: 3
  parameterServerType: standard
```

Change setup.py to the following:

```
"""Setup script for object_detection."""

import logging
import subprocess
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install

class CustomCommands(install):

    def RunCustomCommand(self, command_list):
        p = subprocess.Popen(
        command_list,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        stdout_data, _ = p.communicate()
        logging.info('Log command output: %s', stdout_data)
        if p.returncode != 0:
            raise RuntimeError('Command %s failed: exit code: %s' %
                         (command_list, p.returncode))

    def run(self):
        self.RunCustomCommand(['apt-get', 'update'])
        self.RunCustomCommand(
          ['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'python-tk'])
        install.run(self)

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['Pillow>=1.0', 'protobuf>=3.3.0', 'Matplotlib>=2.1']

setup(
    name='object_detection',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=[p for p in find_packages() if p.startswith('object_detection')],
    description='Tensorflow Object Detection Library',
 cmdclass={
        'install': CustomCommands,
    }
)
```

In object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py, line 24 (before import matplotlib.pyplot as plt) add:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
```

In line 184 of object_detection/evaluator.py, change

```
tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
```

to

```
tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()
```

Finally, in line 103 of object_detection/builders/optimizer_builder.py, change

```
tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
```

to

```
tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18372724)

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Note taken. I added the full solution.

Comment: Kumail, setup.py is part of tf models project. In github it is under models/research. clone or fork it and modify.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the protobuf version. You probably have installed via brew the latest protoc; and protobuf since version 3.5.0 added the `file` field https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/9f80df026933901883da1d556b38292e14836612/CHANGES.txt#L74

So in top of the changes above, in `REQUIRED_PACKAGES` set protobuf version to `'protobuf>=3.5.1'`